# Yii2 : Setting two values of Key in SqlDataProvider

Tags: key, yii2, dataprovider

I have a table `Have_Schedule` (many-to-many relations) in database that contains foreign key from tables :

> **Table** student : *student_id*, student_name
>
> **Table** schedule : *sch_id*, sch_day, sch_time

and

> **Table** Have_Schedule : *student_id*, *sch_id*

And I want to create `DataProvider` using `SqlDataProvider` like this

```
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $sql,
            'totalCount' => $n,
            'key' => '', // <--------- the key
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    'student_name',
                    'sch_day',
                    'sch_time',
                ],
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);
```

The key will used for `ActionColumn`, example : `/view?student_id=1&sch_id=2`.

How to set key's value with `student_id` and `sch_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is not create/use ActionColumn, instead you can use raw-column and show there what you want:

```
[
   'attribute' => 'some_title',
   'format' => 'raw',
   'value' => function ($model) {                      
       return '<a href="'.$yourUrl .'">your Text</a>';
   },
],
```

Comment: @Bhuvanesh please post a new proper question with the code you are using and some better explanation of what you need and eventaally comment me the link to the new question